# How do I enforce margins for a Visio 2013 diagram?

Tags: microsoft-visio-2013

I have a Visio 2013 timeline that spans several pages in landscape view.  When printing, I would like for the margins I set around the page to be observed; however, Visio is running the illustration to the edge of the paper regardless of whether I have set a margin:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried all the Print Options in Visio 2013 ? Try this Forum here: http://visguy.com/vgforum/   and if you get a solution come back and write it here. I am also interested to know if this is possible.

Comment: Thanks @Devid.  I have tried everything including searching visguy.com.  It amazes me that Microsoft would not have this figured out.

Comment: Is this possible in Word 2013 or some other Office 2013 ? 
Maybe you should copy all the pages on one page in Visio 2013 and then print it..